# Relation between the following numbers

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

If:

$4+2=6$

$2+8=26$

$5+8=109$

$7+4=225$

Find $8+6=?$

Comment: Can we add a counter here for hours wasted?

Comment: Can you consider giving a hint? It's been nearly a week since you first posted your question, yet no one has solved it.

Answer (score 3):

The answer might be:

> 31

Because:

> Assuming that every digit left of the '=' operator is a symbolic representation of a value, then we would have:
>  '4' -> 4
>  '2' -> 2
>  '6' -> 6
>  '8' -> 24
>  '5' -> 85
>  '7' -> 221
>  then '8'+'6' (symbolically) would become 24+6 (numerically), therefore '8'+'6' = 30
>  If this is the key, then there would be several alternative solutions, because we could assign different values to the '4' and '2' symbols, like
>  '4' -> 5
>  '2' -> 1
>  '6' -> 6
>  '8' -> 25
>  '8'+'6' = 25+6 = 31
>  Actually I hope to be wrong, because this would be a very inelegant solution :)

Comment: we wouldn't have '6' -> 6, as it is never on the left.  (except for the final question.)